# php redirection working in chorme but not on firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, mozilla

Below is my *`php`* code that caries out the redirection

**Code Snippet :-**

```
     echo "<form action='exp_yogesh.php?id=$id' method='post'>";
     echo "<td> <input type='image'  name='putonline' value='$id'  src='images/on_button.png'  no-repeat; border:none;' alt='submit'>  </td> ";
     echo "<td> <input type='image'  name='putoffline' value='$id'  src='images/off_botton.png'  no-repeat; border:none;'  alt='submit'>  </td> ";
     echo "</form>";
```

**Here's the `exp_yogesh.php` file**

```
<?php
include 'includes/connection.php';
session_start();
$new_id= $_GET['id'];

if (isset($_POST['putonline'])) {
    $query = "UPDATE user SET status= '1' WHERE id= '$new_id'";
    $result = $cid-> query($query);
    if ($result== TRUE) {
        header("Refresh:0.01; url=EidtEmp.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "";
    }


}

if (isset($_POST['putoffline'])) {
    $query = "UPDATE user SET status= '0' WHERE id= '$new_id'";
    $result = $cid-> query($query);
    if ($result== TRUE) {
        header("Refresh:0.01; url=EidtEmp.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "not done";
    }
}
mysqli_close($cid);

?>
```

The above code works properly when I run it on *Google Chrome* but doesn't when I do the same on *Firefox*

Comment: your code is dangerous!!!
if I click "inspect element in browser" and edit this HTML:
<form action='exp_yogesh.php?id=51' method='post'> to this:
<form action="exp_yogesh.php?id=';DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;" method='post'>

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using 
**header('location')** function?

example :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['putonline'])) {
    $query = "UPDATE user SET status= '1' WHERE id= '$new_id'";
    $result = $cid-> query($query);
    if ($result== TRUE) {
        header("location:EidEmp.php");
        die();
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }


}

?>
```

Edited :

Maybe Change Your **header function** with javascript function

i.e

```
echo "<script>window.location.replace('EidtEmp.php');</script>";
```

or try to change 
if (isset($_POST['putonline']))

with

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
```

because Some browsers do not sent the submit button if you hit enter

UPDATED : Try this if you have two conditions

```
<?php
    include 'includes/connection.php';
session_start();
$new_id= $_GET['id'];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
if (isset($_POST['putonline_x'])) {
    $query = "UPDATE user SET status= '1' WHERE id= '$new_id'";
    $result = $cid-> query($query);
    if ($result== TRUE) {
        header("Refresh:0.01; url=EidtEmp.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "";
    }


}

if (isset($_POST['putoffline_x'])) {
    $query = "UPDATE user SET status= '0' WHERE id= '$new_id'";
    $result = $cid-> query($query);
    if ($result== TRUE) {
        header("Refresh:0.01; url=EidtEmp.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "not done";
    }
}
}
mysqli_close($cid);
?>
```

Comment: not working same problem browser shows ulr: http://localhost:8080/aisectfi_new/admin/exp_yogesh.php?id=1 and nothing else !

Comment: why you not use javascript redirect function? like i.e  window.location.replace("EidtEmp.php"); (look at my edited answer)

Comment: Not working Same problem, http://localhost:8080/aisectfi_new/admin/exp_yogesh.php?id=1

Comment: try to change if (isset($_POST['putonline'])) with -->  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )

Comment: Bro its Working, but i have two Condition and this is for only one, how i can use to another one !!

Comment: Bro its working with this code you are right some codes are not working with, browsers do not sent the submit button, i have two condition how can i apply on it please give me suggestion.

Comment: nah!. now you can add your condition below. use if($_POST['putonline']!=null){} and if($_POST['putoffline']!=null).

Comment: or use this condition if(isset($_POST['putonline_x'])) and if(isset($_POST['putoffline_x']))

Comment: It's actually putonline.x and .y - but PHP transforms it into an underscore

Comment: not understanding would you like to write Code please !

Answer (score 0):

Replace top two lines of exp_yogesh.php page.

```
<?php
include 'includes/connection.php';
session_start();
```

With

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include 'includes/connection.php';
```

Change your headers functions to:

```
header("location:EidtEmp.php");
```

Comment: not working browser show url : http://localhost:8080/aisectfi_new/admin/exp_yogesh.php?id=2 and nothing else

Comment: you need to use 'location' param only in the header .. no need to referesh it. like: header("location:EidtEmp.php");

Comment: header("location:EidtEmp.php"); i have tried this chrome working properly and mozila not working !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this; it might work.

```php
echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0';url=EidtEmp.php>");
```

Comment: Not working same problem, by using this code , now chrome gives same http://localhost:8080/aisectfi_new/admin/exp_yogesh.php?id=1